# Symfony 3.1 Define service for a single firewall or get Firewall details inside a service

Tags: service, firewall, symfony-3.1

My requirement is to configure a `service` which will only need to be executed for a particular `firewall`, say `customer`.

Hence, Can it be possible for a service to be only available for a `firewall` OR get the current firewall information in service as an `argument` so that the relevant code can be segregated?

EDIT :

The project supports dynamic domain. So user can customize their url or buy actual domain.

The service actually defines a `Request listener` which is supposed to decide resource of the data of the page, based on the current domain

The system also supports other sub-domains with some different firewall configuration, where Request listener shouldn't invoked. So, I need to restrict part of my service execution based on firewall.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know why you want to restrict the access of the service, Services belongs to application and are design for global access on demand, you can use then in any way you want. A service is never constructed until it's needed. If you define a service and never use it on a request, the service is never created. Load the service only for `customer` firewall when needed. Hope you went through this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: @SunilKumar, Because I use service to initiate a `RequestListener` which will invoke automatically, but I want to restrict it to a particular firewall.